# NOWAIT в Django / MariaDB

Tags: python, база-данных, django, mariadb

Пытаюсь реализовать транзакционность на django 2.2.9. Для базы данных использую mariaDB 10.4, тип таблицы - InnoDB (код упрощён для вопроса):

```
# добыча ресурсов на шахтах региона
@login_required(login_url='/')
@check_player
# @transaction.atomic
def RegionMine(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        with transaction.atomic():
            try:
                players = Player.objects.select_for_update(nowait=True).filter(account=request.user)
            except DatabaseError:
                data = {
                    'responce': 'Персонаж блокирован',
                }
                return JsonResponse(data)
            else:
                for player in players:
                    Player.objects.filter(pk=player.pk).update(
                        energy=player.energy - int(count), gold=player.gold + (int(count) / 10))

                data = {
                    'responce': 'ok',
                }

                return JsonResponse(data)
```

При отправке запроса, запускающего выполнение данного куска кода, получаю следующую ошибку:

> django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: NOWAIT is not supported on this
> database backend.

Подскажите, решаемо ли это в рамках существующей архитектуры (фреймворк-бд)? [Справка MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/wait-and-nowait/), если я её правильно понимаю, говорит о том, что NOWAIT поддерживается с версии 10.3

Comment: Использование NOWAIT с MariaDB добавлено только в Django 3.0, вам нужно обновиться

Comment: @andreymal скажите, а почему у меня, при выставленном в настройке уровне изоляции транзакций SERIALIZABLE, каждая транзакция всё равно получает доступ к прочтению данных?
Я отправляю 15 запросов, из них 11 не отрабатывают по причине блокировки, а случайные четыре выполняются, при этом, если верить отладочной печати, каждый из них получает состояние Player, как если бы начал выполняться первым. То есть остальные выполнившиеся не дожидаются перед прочтением, пока в бд актуализируются данные и снимется блокировка.

Comment: @andreymal буду благодарен, если у нас найдётся полчаса для общения в любом формате, чтобы помочь решить мне эту проблему. Я в основном стараюсь разобраться сам, но было бы хорошо, если бы к вам можно было иногда обращаться с вопросами, а не создавать тут каждый раз новый вопрос :)

Comment: Лучше создавать, таков формат сайта

Comment: @andreymal что создавать?